# Can I save a MultibodyPlant into URDF (or other supported xml type file)?

Tags: drake

For example I can build a model using functions like AddRigidbody and AddJoint. After the model is built, can I save the model into a URDF file or other xml type file? Drake can load model from URDF or SDF using parser but I haven't find function for saving the MultibodyPlant into URDF or SDF. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid Drake doesn't offer that capability (at least not yet).  Contributions are always welcome!